# Fit a non-linear function to data/observations with pyMCMC/pyMC

Tags: python, regression, pymc, probabilistic-programming

I am trying to fit some data with a Gaussian (and more complex) function(s). I have created a small example below.

My first question is, *am I doing it right?*

My second question is, *how do I add an error in the x-direction, i.e. in the x-position of the observations/data?*

It is very hard to find nice guides on how to do this kind of regression in pyMC. Perhaps because its easier to use some least squares, or similar approach, I however have many parameters in the end and need to see how well we can constrain them and compare different models, pyMC seemed like the good choice for that.

```
import pymc
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.ion()

x = np.arange(5,400,10)*1e3

# Parameters for gaussian
amp_true = 0.2
size_true = 1.8
ps_true = 0.1

# Gaussian function
gauss = lambda x,amp,size,ps: amp*np.exp(-1*(np.pi**2/(3600.*180.)*size*x)**2/(4.*np.log(2.)))+ps
f_true = gauss(x=x,amp=amp_true, size=size_true, ps=ps_true )

# add noise to the data points
noise = np.random.normal(size=len(x)) * .02 
f = f_true + noise 
f_error = np.ones_like(f_true)*0.05*f.max()

# define the model/function to be fitted.
def model(x, f): 
    amp = pymc.Uniform('amp', 0.05, 0.4, value= 0.15)
    size = pymc.Uniform('size', 0.5, 2.5, value= 1.0)
    ps = pymc.Normal('ps', 0.13, 40, value=0.15)

    @pymc.deterministic(plot=False)
    def gauss(x=x, amp=amp, size=size, ps=ps):
        e = -1*(np.pi**2*size*x/(3600.*180.))**2/(4.*np.log(2.))
        return amp*np.exp(e)+ps
    y = pymc.Normal('y', mu=gauss, tau=1.0/f_error**2, value=f, observed=True)
    return locals()

MDL = pymc.MCMC(model(x,f))
MDL.sample(1e4)

# extract and plot results
y_min = MDL.stats()['gauss']['quantiles'][2.5]
y_max = MDL.stats()['gauss']['quantiles'][97.5]
y_fit = MDL.stats()['gauss']['mean']
plt.plot(x,f_true,'b', marker='None', ls='-', lw=1, label='True')
plt.errorbar(x,f,yerr=f_error, color='r', marker='.', ls='None', label='Observed')
plt.plot(x,y_fit,'k', marker='+', ls='None', ms=5, mew=2, label='Fit')
plt.fill_between(x, y_min, y_max, color='0.5', alpha=0.5)
plt.legend()
```

I realize that I might have to run more iterations, use burn in and thinning in the end. The figure plotting the data and the fit is seen here below.

[image: Resulting figure from the code.]

The pymc.Matplot.plot(MDL) figures looks like this, showing nicely peaked distributions. This is good, right?

[image]

Comment: Consider changing the title to "fit a _non-linear_ function ...", which I think will help lead other interested readers to this in the future.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> My first question is, am I doing it right?

Yes!  You need to include a burn-in period, which you know.  I like to throw out the first half of my samples.  You don't need to do any thinning, but sometimes it will make your post-MCMC work faster to process and smaller to store.

The only other thing I advise is to set a random seed, so that your results are "reproducible": `np.random.seed(12345)` will do the trick.

Oh, and if I was really giving too much advice, I'd say `import seaborn` to make the `matplotlib` results a little more beautiful.

> My second question is, how do I add an error in the x-direction, i.e. in the x-position of the observations/data?

One way is to include a latent variable for each error.  This works in your example, but will not be feasible if you have many more observations.  I'll give a little example to get you started down this road:

```
# add noise to observed x values
x_obs = pm.rnormal(mu=x, tau=(1e4)**-2)

# define the model/function to be fitted.
def model(x_obs, f): 
    amp = pm.Uniform('amp', 0.05, 0.4, value= 0.15)
    size = pm.Uniform('size', 0.5, 2.5, value= 1.0)
    ps = pm.Normal('ps', 0.13, 40, value=0.15)

    x_pred = pm.Normal('x', mu=x_obs, tau=(1e4)**-2) # this allows error in x_obs

    @pm.deterministic(plot=False)
    def gauss(x=x_pred, amp=amp, size=size, ps=ps):
        e = -1*(np.pi**2*size*x/(3600.*180.))**2/(4.*np.log(2.))
        return amp*np.exp(e)+ps
    y = pm.Normal('y', mu=gauss, tau=1.0/f_error**2, value=f, observed=True)
    return locals()

MDL = pm.MCMC(model(x_obs, f))
MDL.use_step_method(pm.AdaptiveMetropolis, MDL.x_pred) # use AdaptiveMetropolis to "learn" how to step
MDL.sample(200000, 100000, 10)  # run chain longer since there are more dimensions
```

It looks like it may be hard to get good answers if you have noise in `x` and `y`:
[image: model fit with noise in x and y]

Here is [a notebook collecting this all up](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/aflaxman/d4b1ce53b0817a1b7a71).

Comment: This all seems to work as expected, however sometimes, taking `y_fit = MDL.stats()['gauss']['mean']` as the 'best fit' value does not correspond to taking `amp=MDL.stats()['amp']['mean']`(likewise for `size` & `ps`) and calculating the best fit from those. Why is this?

Comment: `E[f(x)]` is not necessarily equal to `f(E[x])`.  I think you will prefer point estimates corresponding to `E[f(x)]`, which is your `y_fit` above.

Comment: But I want to get the best fit parameters, and calculate some values from those. Then the calculated values will not correspond to the line (`y_fit`)?

Answer (score 17):

**EDIT: Important note**
This has been bothering me for a while now. The answers given by myself and Abraham here are correct in the sense that they add variability to x. HOWEVER: Note that you **cannot** simply add uncertainty in this way to cancel out the errors you have in your x-values, so that you regress against "true x". The methods in this answer can show you how adding errors to x affects your regression if you have the true x. If you have a mismeasured x, these answers will not help you. Having errors in the x-values is a very tricky problem to solve, as it leads to "attenuation" and an "errors-in-variables effect". The short version is: having unbiased, random errors in x leads to *bias* in your regression estimates. If you have this problem, check out Carroll, R.J., Ruppert, D., Crainiceanu, C.M. and Stefanski, L.A., 2006. *Measurement error in nonlinear models: a modern perspective*. Chapman and Hall/CRC., or for a Bayesian approach, Gustafson, P., 2003. *Measurement error and misclassification in statistics and epidemiology: impacts and Bayesian adjustments*. CRC Press. I ended up solving my specific problem using Carroll et al.'s SIMEX method along with PyMC3. The details are in Carstens, H., Xia, X. and Yadavalli, S., 2017. *Low-cost energy meter calibration method for measurement and verification.* Applied energy, 188, pp.563-575. It is also available on ArXiv

---

I converted Abraham Flaxman's answer above into PyMC3, in case someone needs it. Some very minor changes, but can be confusing nevertheless.

The first is that the deterministic decorator `@Deterministic` is replaced by a distribution-like call function `var=pymc3.Deterministic()`. Second, when generating a vector of normally distributed random variables,

```
rvs = pymc2.rnormal(mu=mu, tau=tau)
```

is replaced by

```
rvs = pymc3.Normal('var_name', mu=mu, tau=tau,shape=size(var)).random()
```

The complete code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from pymc3 import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# set random seed for reproducibility
np.random.seed(12345)

x = np.arange(5,400,10)*1e3

# Parameters for gaussian
amp_true = 0.2
size_true = 1.8
ps_true = 0.1

#Gaussian function
gauss = lambda x,amp,size,ps: amp*np.exp(-1*(np.pi**2/(3600.*180.)*size*x)**2/(4.*np.log(2.)))+ps
f_true = gauss(x=x,amp=amp_true, size=size_true, ps=ps_true )

# add noise to the data points
noise = np.random.normal(size=len(x)) * .02 
f = f_true + noise 
f_error = np.ones_like(f_true)*0.05*f.max()

with Model() as model3:
    amp = Uniform('amp', 0.05, 0.4, testval= 0.15)
    size = Uniform('size', 0.5, 2.5, testval= 1.0)
    ps = Normal('ps', 0.13, 40, testval=0.15)

    gauss=Deterministic('gauss',amp*np.exp(-1*(np.pi**2*size*x/(3600.*180.))**2/(4.*np.log(2.)))+ps)

    y =Normal('y', mu=gauss, tau=1.0/f_error**2, observed=f)

    start=find_MAP()
    step=NUTS()
    trace=sample(2000,start=start)

# extract and plot results
y_min = np.percentile(trace.gauss,2.5,axis=0)
y_max = np.percentile(trace.gauss,97.5,axis=0)
y_fit = np.percentile(trace.gauss,50,axis=0)
plt.plot(x,f_true,'b', marker='None', ls='-', lw=1, label='True')
plt.errorbar(x,f,yerr=f_error, color='r', marker='.', ls='None', label='Observed')
plt.plot(x,y_fit,'k', marker='+', ls='None', ms=5, mew=1, label='Fit')
plt.fill_between(x, y_min, y_max, color='0.5', alpha=0.5)
plt.legend()
```

Which results in

[y_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvhbd.png)

For errors in x (note the 'x' suffix to variables):

```
# define the model/function to be fitted in PyMC3:
with Model() as modelx:

    x_obsx = pm3.Normal('x_obsx',mu=x, tau=(1e4)**-2, shape=40)

    ampx = Uniform('ampx', 0.05, 0.4, testval=0.15)
    sizex = Uniform('sizex', 0.5, 2.5, testval=1.0)
    psx = Normal('psx', 0.13, 40, testval=0.15)

    x_pred = Normal('x_pred', mu=x_obsx, tau=(1e4)**-2*np.ones_like(x_obsx),testval=5*np.ones_like(x_obsx),shape=40) # this allows error in x_obs

    gauss=Deterministic('gauss',ampx*np.exp(-1*(np.pi**2*sizex*x_pred/(3600.*180.))**2/(4.*np.log(2.)))+psx)

    y = Normal('y', mu=gauss, tau=1.0/f_error**2, observed=f)

    start=find_MAP()
    step=NUTS()
    tracex=sample(20000,start=start)
```

Which results in:

[x_error_graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOh71.png)

the last observation is that when doing

```
traceplot(tracex[100:])
plt.tight_layout();
```

(result not shown), we can see that `sizex` seems to be suffering from 'attenuation' or 'regression dilution' due to the error in the measurement of `x`.

Comment: Link-only answers are not the way of SO. Links may be outdated someday. Put essential informations in your answer (e.g. from the linked page)!

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing your code. One question if I may: When you define x_obsx what is the purpose of the ".random()" method?

Comment: I'm not sure - I suspect I was still learning the ropes on PyMC3. It is probably unnecessary (although I can't test it at the moment).

Comment: Actually, it is unnecessary. I removed it - thank you. Also, I added a note at the top regarding the errors-in-variables effect, which is quite important for the problem.

Comment: why don't you provide a link to your paper on arxiv? Easier and faster than searching for it ..

Comment: Because SO doesn't like external links, AFAIK.

Comment: There are a couple of points I'm wondering about with this answer: initialization with `find_MAP` is no longer a recommended practice in PyMC3 - it could just be removed from `sample`. Instead, some tuning steps could be quite helpful. However, even with `tune=10000` the sampler seems to start overfitting... weird.

Comment: I agree that `find_MAP` is not actually such a good idea. I haven't used PyMC in a while, but if you give my some updated code, I'll replace the old code. The overfitting problem is strange, though. It didn't overfit before.