# Rationale for number of pymc function evaluations

Tags: python, pymc

I am analysing data with code similar to that asked in this [non linear curvefitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24804298/fit-a-non-linear-function-to-data-observations-with-pymcmc-pymc) question:

```
# define the model/function to be fitted.
def model(x, f): 
    amp = pymc.Uniform('amp', 0.05, 0.4, value= 0.15)
    size = pymc.Uniform('size', 0.5, 2.5, value= 1.0)
    ps = pymc.Normal('ps', 0.13, 40, value=0.15)

    @pymc.deterministic(plot=False)
    def gauss(x=x, amp=amp, size=size, ps=ps):
        e = -1*(np.pi**2*size*x/(3600.*180.))**2/(4.*np.log(2.))
        return amp*np.exp(e)+ps
    y = pymc.Normal('y', mu=gauss, tau=1.0/f_error**2, value=f, observed=True)
    return locals()

MDL = pymc.MCMC(model(x,f))
MDL.sample(1e4)
```

In that example I would say that there were three fitting parameters, *amp*, *size* and *ps*.  Let us call the number of parameters being examined **N**.  Now let us call the number of samples to be drawn, **P** (1e4 in this case).  I have observed that the `@deterministic` function `gauss` is called *roughly* **N x P** times.

1. I would like to know the reason why it is **N x P**?
2. Is there an attribute inside `MDL` to find out how many times `gauss` has been called?

Answer (score 0):

`gauss` is called any time its log-probability is needed. PyMC tries to be smart about this, and caches values so that they are only re-calculated when a node's parents change their values. So, `gauss` will be evaluated every time `amp`, `size` and `ps` changes.

Comment: [Here is a notebook that demonstrates this, and a little hack to count how many times `gauss` is called](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/aflaxman/c07c5261bf22f6847098).

Comment: I'm going to look into the AdaptiveMetropolis.  Whilst the likelihood isn't super expensive it is still the limiting computational factor in my real-life calculations, @~10mins for 40000 samples. Significant reductions in numbers of calls to the likelihood function will save a lot of time, especially when I triple the length of **P**. I'm looking forward to be able to do parallel calculations in pymc3, when it gets out of beta.